# Imagem sobrepor div navbar do Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou precisando colocar a logomarca de uma empresa sobre a div navbar do Bootstrap, fazendo com que a metade fique sobre essa div e a outra metade fora (parte cinza) e que acompanhe o topo quando o usuário descer a tela. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei colocar dessa forma, mas não consegui:

```
.logo{
    z-index:99999999999;
    position: relative;
}
```

O Bootstrap:

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="imagens/logo-teste.png" class="logo"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Portfolio
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Blog
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Other Pages
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: E em telas menores quando o menu fica respondido, como vai ficar?

Comment: Oi Hugo. Gostaria de que na versão responsivo, o menu ao ser expandido, ficasse sobre a logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara basicamente é só vc fazer uma regra de `media querie` que bata com o mesmo tamanho do *breacking point* da `navbar`. No caso em `@media (min-width:992px)`, ou seja, apenas para telas maiores que `992px`, vc usa um `translateY()` para jogar o link da logo com a imagem um pouco para baixo, ficando metade pra fora da `navbar`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    @media (min-width:992px) {
        .navbar-brand{
            transform: translateY(50%);
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                      <!-- <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100" class="logo d-inline d-lg-none"> -->
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100" class="logo">
                 </a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Portfolio
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Blog
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Other Pages
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito Hugo. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: @Fox.11 sem problemas meu caro! 